# Git changes to be committed files marked as deleted

Tags: git, github

I am wanting to delete some old files on my repository due to some refactoring. Git is saying my local repo is up-to-date. However when I run `git status` I get the following:

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       deleted:    app/foo1.php
#       deleted:    app/foo2.php
#       deleted:    app/foo3.php
#       deleted:    app/foo4.php
#       deleted:    app/foo5.php
#       deleted:    app/foo6.php
```

Prior to this I used `git rm <file>` to `commit` them.

1. Why is this happening?
2. Can I remove these `deleted` files for good? By this I mean when I
   run `git status` it shows `Everything up-to-date`

`

Comment: `git commit -m "clean up"` and `git push origin master`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using `git rm` you actually deleted the files, but you still have to apply your changes to the local and the remote repositories.

To do so, use the following commands:

```
git commit -m "clean up"
git push origin master
```

The first one commits your changes on your local repository and make them available for the next push to the remote repository. The second command actually delivers the changes.

Of course, feel free to personalize the message for the commit. Moreover, I'm assuming that you are working on the master branch, if it's not set it correctly to the proper one.

Comment: I actually ran `git commit "message"` instead of `git commit -m "message"` - your comment pointed out my stupid mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to `git commit` after using `git rm` .  The `git rm {filename}` command only removes the files in the working tree, but you need to commit this change in order to commit the deletion into history.